How to register async method in ASP.NET WebForms project deployed to Azure Web App?
I'm trying to implement an async call in an ASP.NET WebForms page. I can do this by either registering the async method:
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask())

or adding async to page load:
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

In either case, when I access the page in a browser I get the following error:

Task-returning Page methods are unsupported in the current application
configuration. To work around this, remove the following configuration
switch in Web.config:
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" />
</appSettings>

If I remove this from the web.config (or set the value to "true") everything works as expected. However, when I deploy the code to an Azure Web App, I get the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: <%@ Page AspCompat="true" %> and
 are unsupported in the
current application configuration. To work around this, add the
following configuration switch in Web.config: <appSettings> <add
key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />


So you can see the problem is that the async method needs UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext="true", but the Azure Web App environment needs UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext="false". How can I resolve this?

What exactly do you want to execute asynchronously? Usually that’s a red flag IMHO as people tend to do the wrong things there.

Are you getting the error locally  as well ?

Not getting the error locally, only in Azure.

Can you please share the full code snippet ?

Did you get a chance to check this MSDoc

but the Azure Web App environment needs UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext="false" In this case you can try using multiple Web.config transformations.For local use Web.Debug.config
and Web.Release.config for Azure Deployment (Production).

Just a quick note (although not the cause of your problem) - be very careful when declaring an async void method. You'd normally use async Task. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void

@AndrewB You can't change the vent handlers to return a Task. It's a limitation of how Web Forms was implemented before Task existed. The proper thing to do in Web Forms is to RegisterAsyncTask, which was bolted on to workaround this problem. I've shown this pattern here.

You need to share a full [MCVE]. Do you have AspCompat="true" in your code? Why?

Thanks @mason for the comments.
Even I got the same error.
Error with false value,
_Task-returning Page methods are unsupported in the current application configuration. To work around this, remove the following configuration switch in Web.config:  
<appSettings>  
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" />  
</appSettings>  
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465._

Error with true value
 _This_operation requires the page to be asynchronous (the Async attribute must be set to true)._


Error message clearly says to add Async="true" in the .aspx file.

As suggested in the error message added Async="true" in the .aspx Page directive.


<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPForms._Default" Async="true" %>


Now, I am able to access the app without appsetting UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext key as well as with value="true" with Async="true" in .aspx page.

Deployed the app without the appsetting  and able to access it without any issues.




but the Azure Web App environment needs UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext="false"


If you want to add the appsetting based on your environment, then you can use Web.config Transformation.



Web.config for Local and Web.Release.config for Azure App service (Production).

Web.Release.config:
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>

